# Strategies for predicting 100 binary choices given the previous 100

Tags: forecasting, predictive-models, psychology

Edit: this project ultimately resulted in the paper ["The unpredictable Buridan's ass: Failure to predict decisions in a trivial decision-making task"](http://arfer.net/projects/donkey/paper).

**Background**

As an experimental psychologist, I've long had an interest in binary decision-making tasks. Typically, in such a task, I manipulate a few properties of some hypothetical or real decision, such as the probability of winning a gamble, and ask human subjects which of the two options they'd prefer. Now, however, I'm studying a task in which there is no meaningful difference between the two choices; subjects just make an arbitrary binary choice. The point is to see how well decisions can be predicted in the simplest possible case, as a kind of ceiling (or perhaps floor) for my accuracy in predicting more meaningful decisions.

**The problem**

I'm asking each subject to make 200 binary choices. The question is, using the first 100 as training data, how can I predict the latter 100, using simple accuracy (the proportion of predicted choices equal to the observed choice) as my loss function? I'm not expecting you guys to give me a complete answer so much as ideas of what kinds of methods I should read about. For example, I'm vaguely aware that stochastic processes and time series exist and that this problem can be modeled as one, but I'm not sure which of the many related methods would be most applicable.

You can see many more details about this study, including my attempts so far, on [my website](http://arfer.net/projects/donkey), but here are the most relevant bits:

- I have only 3 subjects, but collecting more is easy since I'm on Mechanical Turk.
- Subject tend to choose one of the options about 50% of the time. So, there's lots of room for improvement over a trivial model.
- I have not only the binary choices but also the response times. While I'm not interested in predicting response times for their own sake, and I don't want to let a predictive model see the response time for a decision it's trying to predict, they might still be useful.
- I've framed my investigation as a separate predictive problem for each subject, but I'm open to using all 200 trials from some subjects in order to train a higher-level model used to predict the latter 100 trials in other subjects. (In such a case, I'd probably use cross-validation to let each subject get a chance to be in the test set.)

Comment: As an aside, wouldn't it be better to ask the first question, then based on that question make a prediction for the second and then once you have the second realized answer, make a prediction for the third, etc., rather than using the first 100 as training to predict the last 100?  I could see where your model might fall apart due to participant boredom after completing the first half of your binary choice questions.  If there is some sort of reliability/degradation effect, this may not be picked up by your model trained on the first 100. This could be reduced by predicting one after another.

Comment: @StatsStudent Predicting the $n$th trial using the previous $n - 1$ trials is definitely easier than predicting 100 trials with only the preceding 100. But, I'm interested in this harder problem of predicting choices without the immediately preceding trials. I suspect boredom would tend to make people fall into repetitive patterns, making prediction easier.

Comment: Interesting thought - I hadn't thought of it like that.  I was thinking that individuals might pay more attention to earlier items than those late in the experiment and as a result of boredom, may end up resorting to essentially random selection whereas initial responses would be based on more informed reasoning because of the need to pay attention to a new cognitive task.  Just providing my insight.  You're the expert here, though.

Comment: @StatsStudent The trick is that in this task, unlike a typical decision-making task, there's nothing to pay attention to. That is, there are no features of the trials to make an informed decision about.

Comment: Ahhh. Now, I'm following.  Excellent!  I'll try to provide a substantive answer later this evening.

Comment: Does what participants choose change from one trial to another? In other words, does the meaning of 0 and 1 for the binary outcome variable changes from trial to trial for each participant and does it change in the same way across participants?

Comment: @IsabellaGhement There's no such change. The options are always identified as "the first option" and "the second option".

Comment: But the question to which these two options apply changes or stays the same across trials for the same participant?

Comment: @IsabellaGhement It's always the same: "To complete this task, just make a bunch of decisions. There are two options to choose from. Nothing special happens
when you make a choice, so choose whichever you like."

Comment: Is that task the same across all trials?

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out if you're measuring the "same" thing but at different times for all participants versus "different" things at different times.

Comment: If you are measuring the "same" thing over time, a learning effect must eventually kick in? So the question might be: how quickly does it kick in?

Comment: @IsabellaGhement It's exactly the same task. All that changes is a number showing how many trials the subject has left to complete. There isn't even feedback confirming for the subject which option they chose.

Comment: Why do the subject have to perform this task so many times? 100 times seems like a large number of times.

Comment: @IsabellaGhement They do it 200 times, not 100 times. I use a large number to have plenty of training data and to be able to assess accuracy precisely even when I'm using zero-one loss.

Comment: If you wanted to model the data from all participants simultaneously, you would need at least 5 participants and then you could presumably use a mixed effects logistic regression model. You will need a predictor in your model - perhaps the trial number will do? You will also need to allow for correlation among your binary response values over time - since the binary outcome values are not equally spaced in time, you'll need to consider a continous AR(1) model or CAR(1).

Comment: I am not aware of an R function that supports what I suggested, but see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/332391/fitting-a-logistic-mixed-model-with-ar1-correlation-structure.

Comment: You may also need to use a higher percentage of your trials for model fitting (e.g., 75% or 80%) and hence a smaller percentage for your prediction.  The further you extrapolate into the future when making predictions, the harder it becomes to justify that the regime under which the model fitting holds will be preserved into that future.

Comment: Even if you analyze the data from each subject separately (i.e., a series of single-subject studies), it seems to me that you would still need to use a binary logistic regression with at least one predictor (e.g., trial number) and continuous AR(1) autocorrelation. If you don't include any predictors, your model will have just an intercept term and will predict the same probability of choosing the desired option in each trial. With the trial number included in the model, the probability will depend on the trial number.

Comment: I look forward to seeing @StatsStudent's recommendations for how to handle your problem!

Comment: There are a few things that are still not clear to me.  Am I correct in assuming that you will be making predictions not just on these subjects again in the future, but on other subjects you've never seen before?  In the future, will you have access to previous trials raw data (like the first 100 individual responses) or will you not be privy to that info or will it possibly be in aggregate only (e.g. percentage of times item A was selected).  Will you be privy to the "trial number" in the future so you know for example, that you are now trying to predict the, say, 209th?

Comment: It's still not also clear, even given the previous comments if subjects see the exact same pairing on the same trial number.  You mentioned previously that the only thing that changes is the number showing how many items there are left to complete. If the same items are displayed at the same time for different subjects, wouldn't these numbers always be the same, unless some subjects just completed fewer items (but in the same order) as other subjects?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Subjects tend to choose one of the options about 50% of the time. So, there's lots of room for improvement over a trivial model."  But if the pairings are essentially meaningless, isn't this exactly what you'd expect:  the choice of either option is essentially a coin flip in this case with the expectation that 50% of the time, option A would be selected.

Comment: @StatsStudent "In the future, will you have access to previous trials raw data (like the first 100 individual responses)" — Yes. "Will you be privy to the 'trial number' in the future" — Yes. "It's still not also clear… if subjects see the exact same pairing on the same trial number" — They do. "If the same items are displayed at the same time for different subjects, wouldn't these numbers always be the same" — Yes; any subject who's so far made 40 of 200 choices will see the number 160. Of course, there's really only one item (presented many times), since all items are identical.

Comment: "But if the pairings are essentially meaningless, isn't this exactly what you'd expect" — No, actually, what I most expected going in is that subjects would play with the two options in the first few trials, then choose the same option every time for the rest of the task, since this would allow one to complete the task by mashing one key. Besides, it's still an open question how well people can generate random numbers. See e.g. Nickerson, R. S. (2002). The production and perception of randomness. *Psychological Review, 109*, 330–357. doi:10.1037/0033-295X.109.2.330

Comment: What kind of binary options are being asked? What is the point for the participants to give an answer? What do you explicitly ask them (write down what you think are 200 random coin flips, or is the question more indirect)?

Comment: You may find some short patterns. But do you really believe that you are gonna have much success predicting anything beyond 110 based on the first 100?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings The options given are described as "the first one" and "the second one". The point for subjects is that they'll be paid for completing the task. What subjects are explicitly asked is "To complete this task, just make a bunch of decisions. There are two options to choose from. Nothing special happens
when you make a choice, so choose whichever you like." Regarding "But do you really believe…" — I don't know. That's why I'm doing the study.

Comment: Are they made aware that they have to continue untill the counter reaches 200?

Comment: With 200 coin flips there are many results possible which you somehow need to train/analyse (some kind of neural network with several layers seems logical to me). How many subjects do you intend to have in the study? There might be some minor influence of the complex "random" human behaviour that you might learn and see in the first 100 flips, and possibly helping you to predict the next 100 but it could be very likely that your fitting method will not get it right without sufficient data to learn the very faint patterns.

Comment: *" I'm open to using all 200 trials from some subjects in order to train a higher-level model "* You are already sort of using higher-level models by asking the question here to humans. These humans might think of some simple structure/formula to predict the next hundred choices based on the first hundred choices. But beyond the trivial case or some models that extrapolates simple patterns, I guess that we can not do much better than some higher level model which is actually getting lots of examples of data (unlike us who are just *guessing* how people might make the 200 choices).

Comment: @MartijnWeterings "Are they made aware that they have to continue untill the counter reaches 200?" — Yes. "How many subjects do you intend to have in the study?" — I haven't decided.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking to use the results of this experiment as a benchmark for prediction in more meaningful experiments, and that your goal is to get the best possible prediction performance in this simple case. However, the best model for predicting meaningless decisions will likely not be the best model for predicting meaningful ones. Given that you want to use this as a benchmark, wouldn't it be better to decide on a model for the meaningful decisions and then see how it does on the meaningless ones?

Comment: @eyeExWhy A model for meaningful decisions generally uses the meaningful features of the options as covariates (e.g., my own [Arfer & Luhmann, 2015](http://arfer.net/projects/builder)), none of which are available here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you approach this by making some conjectures about the nature of the subject choices, and then model these using appropriate models, and test the conjectures by hypothesis tests/model performance.  From the training data you have displayed in the link, it is pretty clear that the choices are not exchangeable, so this is not a simple Bernoulli sequence.  Instead, it seems that your subject tends to choose a long string of consecutive values of the same type and then switch occasionally.  It is reasonable to conjecture that subjects would tend to forget their previous choices once they become far away, and so it might be the case that their choice depends only on the previous choice, and how long they have been pressing it.  This would lead me to start by trying the following conjecture and model.

> **Conjecture 1:** Subject choice depends only on the previous choice and the number of consecutive values of that choice in the present string.  We assume that subject behaviour is symmetric with respect to the choices.
>
> **Modelling:** If this conjecture is true, then we can model the binary sequence $X_1, X_2, X_3, ...$ as follows.  For any time index $t$, define:
>
> $$S_t \equiv \max \{ n \in \mathbb{N} | X_t = X_{t-1} = \cdots = X_{t-n+1} \}.$$
>
> The value $S_t$ tells us the number of consecutive values of the present selection at time $t$.  Under our conjecture we have the model form:
>
> $$\mathbb{P}(X_{t+1} = X_{t}| \mathbf{X}_t = \mathbf{x}_t) = f(s_t) \quad \quad \quad \quad \mathbb{P}(X_0 = 1) = \phi.$$
>
> That is, we formulate our model so that the probability of sticking to the same choice at time $t+1$ is fully determined by $s_t$, which is the number of consecutive values that have been chosen.  By specifying a broad parametric form for the function $f$ (e.g., one that is monotonically decreasing using some simple parametric form) we can then model the data and estimate this function, which then gives a basis for making predictions of future values.  We note that this gives a model form that can be analysed as a Markov chain with state-space $(X_t, S_t)$.

---

> **Conjecture 2:** Subject choice depends only on the previous choice and the number of consecutive values of that choice in the present string.  We **do not** assume that subject behaviour is symmetric with respect to the choices.
>
> **Modelling:** This conjecture is a variation of conjecture 1 where we generalise to allow the probability of sticking/switching to be non-symmetric in the choices.  Under this generalisation we have the model form:
>
> $$\mathbb{P}(X_{t+1} = X_{t} = i| \mathbf{X}_t = \mathbf{x}_t) = f_i(s_t) \quad \quad \quad \quad \mathbb{P}(X_0 = 1) = \phi.$$
>
> That is, we again formulate our model so that the probability of sticking to the same choice at time $t+1$ is fully determined by $s_t$, but now we have two functions $f_0$ and $f_1$ for the two different choices.  We can again specify a parametric form for these functions, model the data and estimate the functions, which then gives a basis for making predictions of future values.  This generalised model form can also be analysed as a Markov chain with state-space $(X_t, S_t)$ (with a slightly generalised transition matrix).

---

**Testing the conjectures:** The above model forms would allow you to model your data under some basic conjectures about subject behaviour.  Testing these conjectures could be done in a number of ways, either by nesting these models inside a broader model and doing explicit cross-validation, or by doing some kind of hypothesis test for the conjecture by formulating a test statistic that becomes large when the conjecture is false.

I will leave it to others to specify other models that could be applied to this type of data.  There are a myriad of possibilities, but the above strike me as reasonable models to start with.  Personally, I would start by fitting a model of a form similar to the ones above, with function(s) $f$ that have some simple parametric form (and maybe test some montonically decreasing functions against broader options).  With $n=100$ data points you should have a reasonable amount of data to estimate a parametric form for such a function.  Have a look at the RMSE of predictions from such a model and see if they are any good.

Comment: These seem like good ideas. I'll give it a shot and tell you how it goes.

Comment: Sadly, this method, too, produces trivial predictions for two subjects, and does worse than a trivial model for the third ([results](http://arfer.net/projects/donkey/notebook#sec--regression-run-length)). I used a logistic regression model with these predictions: the number of previous consecutive choices for 0, the number of previous consectuive choices for 1, the squares of these, and a dummy indicating whether the previous choice was for option 1.

Comment: Sorry you only got half the bounty. I expected to have 24 hours to award the bounty after the period ended, but it seems that Stack Exchange removed that "grace period".

Comment: No problem - sorry the method didn't get you good results.  Did you try fitting it on all $n=200$ data points, or just a single series?

Comment: Just the first 100 for each of the three subjects. I did at least think of some other things to try since, and also came up with an argument that I shouldn't expect decent performance without a hierarchical model.